# Django - Prepare objects from a view for Current User

Tags: python, django, django-views

Consider this model

```
class Exercise(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name

class Score(models.Model):
  """Scores of users by exercise"""
  exo = models.ForeignKey(Exercise)
  user = models.ForeignKey(User)
  score = models.IntegerField()
  class Meta:
    unique_together = (('exo', 'user',),)
```

I have a template which displays the `Exercise`s.

```
<ul>
  {% for exo in exos %}
    <li>{{ exo }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Here is the view

```
def view_exos(request):
  """Lists Exercises"""
  objs = {
    'exos': Exercise.objects.all(),
  }
  return render_to_response('content/contents.html', objs
  , context_instance=RequestContext(request)
  )
```

Now I'd like to display the `Score` of the current user in front of each `Exercise` (if there is one) in order to access it from the template in this manner:

```
<li>{{ exo }} - {{ exo.user_score }}</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I'd do would be to get all the user's current scores up front, create a dictionary mapping exercise to score, then add the score as an attribute of each exercise. Something like:

```
user_scores = request.user.score_set.all()
score_dict = dict((sc.exo_id, sc.score) for sc in user_scores)
exos = Exercise.objects.all()
for ex in exos:
    ex.current_user_score = score_dict.get(ex.id)
```

Now each exercise in `exos` has a `current_user_score` attribute, which is the current user's score for that exercise (or None).

Comment: Why `User.score_set.all()`? I think that should be a User instance instead.

Comment: Yes, sorry, meant `request.user...` - changed.

Answer (score 1):

`django.contrib.auth` has a [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#authentication-data-in-templates) that adds a `user` variable to the template context, referencing the current user. This can enable you to get all scores for the current user, then you can create a template filter that returns the score for a particular exercise.

**In a file named `exercises.py` within a `templatetags` package**.

[Put the package in the folder of one of your apps in `INSTALLED_APPS`. Remember `templatetags` must be a valid Python package ie. with an `__init__.py`]

```
from django.template import Library
register = Library()

@register.filter
def score_for_exercise(scores, exercise):
    s = scores.filter(exo=exercise)
    if s:
        return s[0].score
    return None
```

**In the template:**

```
{% load exercises %}
{% with user.score_set.all as user_scores %}
<ul>
  {% for exo in exos %}
    {% with user_scores|score_for_exercise:exo as score %}
    <li>{{ exo }}{% if score %} - {{score}}{% endif %}</li>
    {% endwith %}
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Actually I prefer to use the Roseman's view technique, that allows me to avoid creating a template filter.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add an attribute to your `Exercise`:

```
class Exercise(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def user_score(self):
        return Score.objects.get(exo=self).score
```

Comment: Isn't this going to bring me the scores for all the users ?